# What is the best way of integrating vite and vue with Django without using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, cdn, vite

I have a Django app, I want to use vuejs with vite as the frontend, I don’t want to use Django Rest Framework.

Is there a way to make this stack work properly?

I tried install vite in a separate folder within the Django project directory and I am not sure how to connect the vue files with Django

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide how you're going to use Vuejs. As a complete replacement of Django templates or simply as an enhancement of them?

For the second option, you don't need to do much. Just load Vue as a script.

For the first, you'd need both Vite dev server and Django server running. Then from .vue files you'll be able to call routes on your Django server (given you set them up). Django has JsonResponse class, you'll want to use it if you don't want to use Django REST. Don't forget about CORS.

Keep in mind, that only applies to development.

Comment: With the second option it will be like added jQuery to it right? No need to add the .vue file extension right?

Comment: yeah, it's explained well there: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/ways-of-using-vue.html